# flex support for REST methods

Tags: apache-flex, rest

does the latest sdk now support RESTful methods like PUT and DELETE using their HTTPService?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the [HTTPService documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html) it does.

Comment: that's according to their documentation but in reality it doesn't.

Comment: do you have useProxy set to true?

Comment: would that make the REST methods DELETE and PUT work? I would like to know beforehand because its rather a little more work I have to do to upgrade my SDK to a newer version.

Thanks.

Comment: The documentation says this: "When you do not go through the server-based proxy service, you can use only HTTP GET or POST methods."   See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html.

Answer (score 0):

OK it seems like you need to use a separate server like BlazeDS in order to gain access to the PUT and DELETE methods.  I haven't tried this personally, I feel like it is totally lame that this has to be the only solution.  When I was using FLEX 3 with Rails 2, I was able to achieve RESTfulness by doing the ?_method=PUT hack.  But, when I upgraded to Rails 3, it isn't working anymore :(

I been doing some readin trying to straighten this out.  I also posted on here ([Rails 3 is "_method=PUT" still supposed to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732183/rails-3-is-methodput-still-supposed-to-work)) but I havent gotten any responses yet....  I really hope I don't need to trash FLEX because of Rails 3 not supporting the _method=PUT hack.

Comment: I'm looking for a RESTConnector (probably build off of Socket) that re-implements the HTTP protocol just so I can do HTTP authentication as well as DELETE and PUT.

Or I'll try and make it if no one who actually knows what they are doing has built this. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

PUT and DELETE methods can be supported in the latest SDK (eg. Apache Flex 4.12.0) by using the 'X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE' request header attribute.

Reference: http://blog.arulprasad.com/2010/12/http-put-delete-from-actionscript-rest.html

Note, the request header must be in CAPITALs, not mixed case as in the article.