# Flash Player 9 vs Flash Player 10 with FLEX 3, ?_method=PUT/DELETE not working?

Tags: rest, flex3, flash

I have a FLEX 3 frontend that worked fine in FlashPlayer 9.  But now that I've upgraded to FlashPlayer10, the **?_method=PUT/DELETE** hack is not working anymore.  All those requests show up as a POST on the backend now.  I did some reading and it sounds like I need to use  as3httpclientlib AND run a socket policy server to give access to port 80 (or any other port) in order to use as3httpclientlib.  So my question is: are you freakin kidding me?  How is it that, in earlier versions of Flex/flash player, all I had to do was add a simple string ("_method=") to the url.  But now I have to do the hokey pokey AND turn my self around?  Really?  Please someone tell me that I've got this all wrong, and that _method= is, in fact, still supported.  Otherwise, its BYE BYE FLEX/FLASH PLAYER - NEVER AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you very much, my friend, just had similar noise with authentication headers in new one Security Policy from Adobe. Anyway, if you'll share your code, maybe I could help you, because your goal is not clearly explained in your post, Buddy. So let me know please, cause java sandbox and silverlight are not the better way in this case. But maybe some javascript stuff could save our time.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  I'm already in the process of re-writing the FLEX code.  Using Flash Player is a horrible idea, I should have never went that direction to begin with.  Hopefully others can learn from my mistake!  I think flash player is on the way out...