# Rails 3 equivalent for controller.process (building seamless user authentication)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, authentication, ruby-on-rails-2

I've been trying to develop a controller action for user authentication so I can do something like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
...
```

and have an authentication action that redirects back to the previous page after the user is authenticated.  I'm aware that there are store-and-redirect approaches to solve this problem.  However, this doesn't work for anything that requires a non-GET action, i.e. deleting a post.

I've found a [solution for Rails 2](http://classic-web.archive.org/web/20080605121920/http://last10percent.com/2008/05/26/post-redirects-in-rails/) that involves using the `controller.process` method to call a POST action from another controller.  This is deprecated in Rails 3, though.  Is there some equivalent method in Rails 3?  I can't find much documentation on the old `controller.process` command to begin with.

If someone has a suggestion for another approach, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Take a look at devise, perhaps you won't need to reinvent the wheel - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Thank you.  I'm actually using devise and that `authenticate_user` action is from Devise.  This works just fine for GET actions, but if I want to authenticate before doing a PUT/POST/DELETE action, authentication won't be seamless.  The user will click a link, authenticate, then go to some default page or the previous page.  They'll have to re-click after the action.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem in Rails 3 with controller.process being deprecated.
Below is my failed attempt to use Rack::MethodOverride in place of controller.process (which was working for me in Rails 2). The error from ro.call below is:

ThreadError in User sessionsController#create
thread 0xb592b994 tried to join itself

def demo

```
params = {'action' => 'create', 'controller' => 'user_sessions', 
        "commit"=>"Submit", "user_session"=>{"username"=>"demo", "password"=>"demo"}}

request.env['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST'

# Throw out existing params and merge the stored ones
request.parameters.reject! { true }
request.parameters.merge!(params)

request.path_parameters.reject! { true }
request.path_parameters.merge!('action' => 'create', 'controller' => 'user_sessions')

request.POST["HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE"] = 'POST'
ro = Rack::MethodOverride.new Rails.application
ro.call request.env
if response.redirected_to
  @performed_redirect = true
else
  @performed_render = true
end
```

end

Might anyone know how to correctly use Rack::MethodOverride to send a post request?

Comment: I put this idea aside for now, but I'm still on the lookout for easier ways to implement it.  I believe @Roman's answer wasn't suggesting to _use_ MethodOverride, but to write your own Rack middleware that would have similar behavior to MethodOverride.  When I tried doing this, I realized there was a lot more I had to learn than I had time for.  You may want to look at the accepted answer [for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732183/rails-3-is-method-put-still-supposed-to-work).  With MethodOverrideWithParams, you might get it to work by playing around with the routes/URL

Answer (score 1):

You can store the method together with the url the user was redirected from in the session, and then fake it later. You'll have to do it on the Rack middleware level though. Check Rack::MethodOverride in lib/rack/methodoverride.rb for example.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I'll try to get some middleware code to do this.  Would faking these requests be against some Rails convention?

Comment: I'm not DHH to speak about Rails conventions ;) But what I'm afraid here, is some edge-cases that won't be covered. Like a failed auth, which will lead to loops, etc.

Comment: That's a concern I had even with a non-rack level solution.  I'll try this out and see if I can working.  I'd like to leave the question open a little longer just to see if someone can answer the part about `controller.process` being gone in Rails 3.  This sounds like it should work, though

Comment: By the way, would you happen to have some code that uses Rack::MethodOverride?  I'm not finding any examples on google

Comment: MethodOverride is used in order to work-around a fact, that browsers don't issue PUT or DELETE. So when there's a _method parameter in the form, the rack middleware takes it out, and changes the method that the controller sees.