# ruby-on-rails routes problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache-flex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following routes:

```
     people GET    /people(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"people"}
            POST   /people(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"people"}
 new_person GET    /people/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"people"}
edit_person GET    /people/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"people"}
     person GET    /people/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"people"}
            **PUT    /people/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"people"}**
            DELETE /people/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"people"}
```

However when my flex client calls for update with

```
" **<mx:HTTPService id = "update"
url='http://localhost:3000/people/{grid.selectedItem.id}.xml?_method=put**"
```

I get the error

```
**ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/people/1.xml"**.
```

Even when I explicitly (for troubleshooting) convert the line to `**url='http://localhost:3000/people/1.xml?_method=put"` the error persists.*

I can type `"http://localhost:3000/people/1.xml"` in the address bar without error.

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Rack based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732183/rails-3-is-method-put-still-supposed-to-work

Comment: @Jibaly The previous solution does not seem to work in part because middleware swap in config/environment.rb results in an error:"undefined variable"

Answer (score 2):

When you type `http://localhost:3000/people/1.xml` it is GET request.

You need to make a `PUT` request which is actually `POST http://localhost:3000/people/1.xml?_method=PUT`

So you need to make somehow `POST` request from Flex

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. The full text of the call from flex is as follows:
 <mx:HTTPService id = "update"
    url="http://localhost:3000/people//{grid.selectedItem.id}.xml?_method=put"
    contentType="application/xml"
    resultFormat ="e4x"
    method="POST"
    fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.toString())"
    result="handleResult(event.result as XML)"/> As you can see it is a POST request.