# IE9 AJAX call to Rails fails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer, xdomainrequest

I am trying to sent a PATCH request from the client to the rails backend.

This works fine in FF/Chrome and IE10+.

The problem seems to be XDomainRequest.  I am using jQuery and tried to just send a POST  request and change it to PATCH with`'X-Http-Method-Override': 'PATCH'`.

Unfortunately it seems that IE9 does not allow to set custom headers, since it does not show up in the HTTP Request.

On the backend I get errors, because the route for a POST request is not found.

I also tried appending `_method=patch` to the URL params and `_method: "patch"` to the request body, but it still doesnt work. Also I can not change the Content-Type to anything else than Plain/Text in IE9.

Is there any way to sent a POST request from IE9 and get it recognized as a PATCH Request by my Rails Backend?

Comment: Providing `_method: 'PATCH'` in the request body should cause the Rack middleware to treat the request as a PATCH request. I believe it is case sensitive though which is why your previous attempt failed.

Comment: Also `Rack::MethodOverride` no longer takes the `_method` query string parameter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732183/rails-3-is-method-put-still-supposed-to-work